# Does UWP has synchronic file read/write API?

Tags: c++, uwp

I am porting a win32 dll c++ code to UWP. I want to check a file is exist in a target folder and then do something. But UWP file API is Async API, is there any workaround method to call these Async API as a synchronic API?

for example:
In win32 code:

```
void test()
{
    if(file.isExist())
    {
         doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you want synchronous file access?

Comment: because i want to create some folder first, then create some files in this folder later.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, UWP supports low-level Win32 APIs like `CreateFile2`, `ReadFile` and `WriteFile` in addition to CRT functions like `fopen` and STL objects like `fstream`.

Note that access to file locations outside of your container will be blocked when using these APIs, although that is changing with the "RS4" release of Windows 10 (I don't know the consumer name yet). See [this Channel 9 video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Ch9Live/Windows-Community-Standup/Kevin-Gallo-February-2018) for more information on the `broadFileSystemAccess` capability.